# How can i change excel cell value

Tags: c#

i m exporting data from gridview to excel. 
This is my exported column:

```
POSTING KEY
1
50
50
```

but the column seems in the gridview like that:

```
POSTING KEY
01
50
50
```

Excel convert my string values to numeric  when after export. But i must see "01". How can i change  excel cell type or cell value in code when before save file.?

Answer (score 0):

From Excel, highlight the column or the cell, right click and select "Format Cells", under the "Number" tab, click "Custom" under the Category:.  In the Type: textbox, key in "00".

Answer (score 0):

You can export text with a apostrophe suffix. for e.g. to display 01 instead of 1, you need to set cell's value as '01 and not just 01
Excel will take this value as text instead of number. But in this case you will see a Error SamrtTag in Excel saying "Number stored as Text" which can be turned off from preferences.

Answer (score 0):

When you read or write a cell there are two values you can look at. The first one is value (e.g. **cell.Value**) which is the one you are probably setting. The second is NumberFormat (e.g. **cell.NumberFormat**). This is a string a will represent the format of the value when displayed in Excel, set this to an appropriate value (use the string representations in Excel if you're not sure which one you want).